# TWTweetComposeViewController alerts that No twitter Profile found

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, twitter, ios7

I'm using `TWTweetComposeViewController` for tweet a message. In IOS 6.1 working perfectly, but incase of IOS 7, the twitter account from the device was fetched and properly getting user details from the twitter site. while opening tweet sheet, a alert the saying "no twitter account configured.you can add or create a twitter account in settings".

note: a twitter account  has been configured in settings.[image]

i encounted same problem in `SLComposeViewController`

UPDATE: working in device not in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the Simulator (or Device you are testing on) and go into settings and log into a twitter account on there for this to work.

Comment: check my note: a twitter account has been configured in settings.

Comment: It could be something to do with the X-Code being in beta still.